# why i have this error("linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)")?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i don't know why i have this error("linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)") on my IOS app.[image]

Comment: Open workspace file from ur project not xcodeProj file

Comment: omg, i feel so stupid... thanks friend!